# Programmatically detect resizing of image will result in a loss of quality or not

Tags: image-processing, graphics, printing

I think I know the answer already, but I'd love to be surprised and learn.  I'm trying to figure out what the rule of thumb usually is for something like this.

I have an application where users can scale how much bigger or smaller they want an image resized to, for it to later be printed on paper.  I would love to warn them that depending on the size of the image in question (and each would be different), going above or below a certain resize point is going to make the image look very bad and they shouldn't continue.

**Keep in mind that aspect ratios will always be preserved.**

Is there any way to figure this out programmatically?  I don't mean an exact science here, but I'm hoping it's more than just the human eye test.  Is it safe to say anytime a raster image is shrunk or stretched by 50% (or 25%?, 75%?), the user should be warned?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality is likely to be judged by the *sharpness* of the result. This can be estimated by using the DPI of the image, that is the number of pixels in the original (either dimension) divided by the number of inches it will be printed at; the resize ratio really doesn't matter except that it determines the printed size. The actual limits will depend on your application, but I'd start with a limit of 150 DPI or above and adjust from there.